# Keeping the application state - deploy/install apk

Tags: android, state

I'm trying to have my application minimized when paused and then when it's resumed, it should be restored to its previous state, not recreated. This works perfectly when deploying the application on a device/emulator from Eclipse.

The problem occurs when I get the apk (either from bin\ or from Project -> Android tools -> Export signed application package) and install it on a device with a file browser (Astro): the application is destroyed when paused and then recreated.

I can call **moveTaskToBack(true);** in my activity, yet it will still be recreated when launching it.

All the discussions around this are based on achieving the opposite: closing the application when minimizing it. Is there any way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to have my application minimized when paused and then when it's resumed, it should be restored to its previous state, not recreated.

That is normal behavior for short pause periods, assuming that by "paused" you mean "the user went into another app via HOME, Recent Tasks, etc.", and assuming that by "minimized" you mean "goes into the background".

The key is "short pause periods". Android will terminate your background process eventually, either on its own to free up RAM for other processes, or on user request (e.g., swipe from Recent Tasks). How long "eventually" is depends on many factors, none of which are under your control.

Hence, you have no choice but to handle both the "minimized and restored" and "minimized and terminated" scenarios.

Comment: 20/20 times the behavior is the same: for manually installed APKs, the application is recreated. For eclipse deployed APKs, the application is simply resumed. Can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If you press the `back` button your app will get closed and `onDestroy()` gets called. This is intendet behavior. If you press the `Home` Button, only `onPause()` should get called. I cannot think of any method to prevent an app-close if you press the the back-button.

Comment: you may catch `onBackPressed()` and ignore if you like. not recommended, though, except in games.

Comment: I have overridden the Back button event and now use    moveTaskToBack(true); when it's pressed.